# How to make the functions be aware of each other when they are called, e.g. when using the ElementTree package

Tags: python-3.x, xml, function, elementtree

If the title question is not worded clearly, the code below will explain it better. This code works fine:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import sys
import os
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from xml.etree.ElementTree import *

country_arg = 'usa'
transport_name_arg = 'train'
route_data = "some route"

world = ET.Element('world')
country = ET.SubElement(world, 'country')
country.text = country_arg
event = ET.SubElement(world, 'event')
transport = ET.SubElement(event, 'transport')
transport.set('name',transport_name_arg)
route = ET.SubElement(event, 'route')

comment = Comment(route_data)
route.append(comment)
c = ET.SubElement(event, 'c')

tree = ET.ElementTree(world)
tree.write("filename.xml")
```

However I need to create and use functions calling them in different places of my actual script. I thought that when the function runs it is the same as the block of code runs it represents. However it appears that the results of function_1 are not kept in memory? 
Here is the same script as above but the code is separated into the two functions and it does not work, as if the results of function_1 are lost once the function_2 is called:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import sys
import os
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from xml.etree.ElementTree import *

country_arg = 'usa'
transport_name_arg = 'train'
route_data = "some route"

def function_1():
    world = ET.Element('world')
    country = ET.SubElement(world, 'country')
    country.text = country_arg
    event = ET.SubElement(world, 'event')
    transport = ET.SubElement(event, 'transport')
    transport.set('name',transport_name_arg)
    route = ET.SubElement(event, 'route')

def function_2():
    comment = Comment(route_data)
    route.append(comment)
    c = ET.SubElement(event, 'c')

function_1()
function_2()

tree = ET.ElementTree(world)
tree.write("filename.xml")
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test-WITH-functions-xml.py", line 26, in <module>
    function_2()
  File "test-WITH-functions-xml.py", line 22, in function_2
    route.append(comment)
NameError: name 'route' is not defined
```

Comment: Do you know about return values? And what scope is?

Comment: Because those topics are what you need to read about next after being introduced to functions.

Comment: Good job on learning a new language and good luck in your studies

Comment: Yeah :) I have just read. I need to declare every var inside the funct as global. Not a rocket science. ;)

Comment: No don't do that. Globals are not a good way to pass information between functions. Use return values and function arguments.

Comment: The problem with globals is that you can't keep track of who's using them once the project gets to a certain size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works, thank you all, good learning experience:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import sys
import os
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from xml.etree.ElementTree import *

country_arg = 'usa'
transport_name_arg = 'train'
route_data = "some route"

def function_1():
    global world
    global country
    global event
    global transport
    global route
    world = ET.Element('world')
    country = ET.SubElement(world, 'country')
    country.text = country_arg
    event = ET.SubElement(world, 'event')
    transport = ET.SubElement(event, 'transport')
    transport.set('name',transport_name_arg)
    route = ET.SubElement(event, 'route')

def function_2():
    global comment
    global c
    comment = Comment(route_data)
    route.append(comment)
    c = ET.SubElement(event, 'c')

function_1()
function_2()

tree = ET.ElementTree(world)
tree.write("filename.xml")
```